# Orientation listener not working in Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-orientation, pager

I've a Project Android Tab Pager with Fragments. And there're two inner fragments in Main fragment.

- Home Tab (Fragment)

  - Inner main fragment 1
  - Inner main fragment 2
- Next Tab 1 (Fragment)
- Next Tab 2 (Fragment)

If i launch Inner main fragment 2 and i tap on anther next tab. when i came back to the main fragment, the Inner main fragment 2 is not visible and it goes to the Home Tab automatically. Finally i fixed that issue using this code,

```
 <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_operation" >
 </activity>
```

But the problem is, i want to set deference layout with orientation change (portrait/landscape) for a inner fragment in the main fragment. But It's not working and orientation listener is not working in an inner fragment.

Already I've created two deference XML layouts (layout-large-land and layout-land)for a single inner fragment. But the device when rotate UI not change. How can i solve this issue.